# How to Import the geometry/feature collection which is in GeoJSON format into Google Earth Engine?

Tags: geojson, remote-sensing, google-earth-engine, text, google-fusion-tables

**I have a GeoJSON file. I have opened it in Sublime Text Editor**

How can I import it in Google Earth Engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to import GeoJSON geometry objects directly.

Here is an example of a MultiPolygon:

```
feature_geometry =
{
'type': 'MultiPolygon',
'coordinates': [[[
    [-90, 24],
    [-90.001, 40],
    [-90.001, 39.001],
    [-90, 31.001],
    [-90, 27]
]]]
}
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments, you can directly convert geojson into a shapefile using qgis or ogr then import into GEE.

Comment: No, I am having a file with so much data like wards for a corporation/city. I found a way to directly convert geojson into .shp using qgis and then importing into GEE. I am looking for an easier way.

Comment: An easier way may be a python script to perform the task through automation. That's what comes to my mind for this in the case you are looking to make it "easier"

Comment: How much easier can it get, than 1 conversion followed by 1 upload? You can paste the complete content of the GeoJSON into the code editor, like this answer suggests, but if you have a large file that is bound to crash your browser.

Comment: Actually, I have asked the question before I did find the way :)